# Query Inside For Loop Question

Tags: trigger

I need to add some functionality to this trigger but have just noticed a query inside a for loop. Can anyone confirm if this would potentially be a problem even though it's not in the main trigger loop? - eg for (account a: trigger.new)...

Thanks

```
 // Add bonus id to map           
    map <id, bonus__c> bonusIdMap = new map<id, bonus__c>();    
    for (bonus__c bc:[select Date_Payment_1_Due__c, Date_Payment_2_Due__c, opportunity__c from bonus_calculator__c where id in :ids])
    {
        bonusIdMap.put (bc.opportunity__c, bc);   
    }
```

Comment: The question is what will happen if there are say 101 Account objects? If the query you quote is run once only (i.e. it is not in the main trigger loop) then there is no problem. If it is run 101 times (i.e. it is in the main trigger loop) then the SOQL governor limit will be exceeded. Sounds like you are probably OK.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Keith. I suspect perhaps one record every 3 months would actually meet the criteria defined in this trigger so it should be ok. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet is correct. It will not cause any issues if this is running independently.
It will cause issues if the loop is called more than 100 times
1) if your for loop is nested within another loop.
2) if there are cascaded triggers means one of the trigger is invoking this trigger every time a record is inserted. I am assuming that is not the case with you.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Sounds like it should be fine. All the best.